# Cache of operating system - how to load data into it?

Tags: caching, io, operating-system

I did read a following article:
http://surbhistechmusings.blogspot.com/2016/05/neo4j-performance-tuning.html

I come across

> We loaded the files into OS cache

It is about loading file (on local disk) into OS cache.
Could you explain me how to do such loading?
And tell me please if such cache is in-memory?
What is cause that it can help?

Comment: It's pretty much to load files from the disk to some RAM, they call "OS Cache".

Comment: How to do it ? Simply, loading in C program (read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is done simply by reading files most of the time.

Actually modern OSes fill the unused parts of your RAM with filesystem caches. And this is done when apps open files : the first time data is read from disk but then it is (transparently) read from memory. This is why an app you've just closed seems to start much faster the next time you launch it provided you did not shut down your computer between the two launches.

Many software rely on this mechanism like Kafka, PostgresSQL and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of that blog. This is what I had used https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/
You can read up, extensive literature around it.

The idea behind doing this is ,almost every lookup is a random disk read which is veryyy slow, however if the file is in the os cache, it becomes much much faster.